# Inverse Laplace Transform of $\frac{e^{a\sqrt{s}}}{s^2}$ where $a$ is a positive number?

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-laplace

I'm trying to invert the following equation back into the time domain

$$\frac{c}{s^{2}} \bigg(2-e^{-a\sqrt{s}}+e^{a\sqrt{s}}\bigg)$$ where ${a}$ and ${c}$ are positive constants.

I'm ok with solving the first two terms within the big brackets but I don't know how to deal with $\frac{e^{a\sqrt{s}}}{s^2}$. Are there any suggestions about how to tackle it?

Comment: are you sure that $a>0$?

Comment: Yes, a is a positive constant. Even if it wasn't though, it's the fact that the equation has both -a and +a that is causing grief.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that the convolution of the functions $f$ and $g$ is given by $$f\ast g=\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$$
Also, we can see that $$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{F(s)G(s)\right\}=f\ast g$$
Now, note that
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{\exp(a\sqrt{s}}{s^{2}}\right\}=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s^{2}}\cdot \exp(a\sqrt{s})\right\}=f(t)\ast g(t)$$
where $F(s)=\frac{1}{s^{2}}$ and $G(s)=\exp(a\sqrt{s})$.

Comment: Thanks, the convolution is clear and I was able to use that for the part with the expression with exp(-a * sqrt(s)). I'm not sure what to do about the laplace inverse of exp(+a * sqrt(s)) though.